# Multiple aggregations and group by in single query

Tags: mysql, hive, hiveql

I have an SQL table with roughly the following structure:

`Employee| date | department | Country | Designation`

What I would like is to get results with the following structure:

`count_emp_per_department | count_emp_per_country | count_emp_per_designation |`

Currently I am using `UNION ALL`, that is constructing a query similar to that one:

```
SELECT emp_ID, NULL, count(1)
FROM employee
GROUP BY country
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, emp_ID, count(1)
FROM film
GROUP BY designation
```

Is this the most effective way to perform multiple aggregations and return all of them in a single result set in Hive?

#### Kindly share if you new approach which can optimize/enhance performance.

Comment: Select **ONE** DBMS, and remove unrelated tag(s). If this is MySQL - specify its version.

Comment: Count of employees per someting (not totally) without this "something" makes no sense.

Comment: @Akina I tagged MySQL for greater reach, as HiveQL is pretty similar to MySQL.

Comment: HiveQL supports [CTE](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Common+Table+Expression) and [window functions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics) - use them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, My first approach was CTE only, can you please share how can I use Window Function in my Scenario, I would love to learn this with an example. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please solve firstly the problem with "value for an entity without the entity itself". For example show example output with calculated values...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether its a real requirement.. as the output isnt that useful.. anyway

Here is the structure and query.

```
+-----------+------------+----------+
| col_name  | data_type  | comment  |
+-----------+------------+----------+
| emp       | int        |          |
| dt        | date       |          |
| dept      | string     |          |
| country   | string     |          |
| desig     | string     |          |
+-----------+------------+----------+

+--------+-------------+---------+------------+----------+
| t.emp  |    t.dt     | t.dept  | t.country  | t.desig  |
+--------+-------------+---------+------------+----------+
| 1      | 2020-02-02  | human   | usa        | hr       |
| 2      | 2020-02-02  | dir     | usa        | hr       |
| 3      | 2020-02-02  | dir     | canada     | it       |
+--------+-------------+---------+------------+----------+


with q1 as (select dept,count(*) as deptcount from t group by dept),
q2 as (select country,count(*) as countrycount from t group by country),
q3 as (select desig,count(*) as desigcount from t group by desig)
select *  from q1, q2, q3;
```

output will be like this..

```
+----------+---------------+-------------+------------------+-----------+----------------+
| q1.dept  | q1.deptcount  | q2.country  | q2.countrycount  | q3.desig  | q3.desigcount  |
+----------+---------------+-------------+------------------+-----------+----------------+
| dir      | 2             | canada      | 1                | hr        | 2              |
| dir      | 2             | usa         | 2                | hr        | 2              |
| dir      | 2             | canada      | 1                | it        | 1              |
| dir      | 2             | usa         | 2                | it        | 1              |
| human    | 1             | canada      | 1                | hr        | 2              |
| human    | 1             | usa         | 2                | hr        | 2              |
| human    | 1             | canada      | 1                | it        | 1              |
| human    | 1             | usa         | 2                | it        | 1              |
+----------+---------------+-------------+------------------+-----------+----------------+
```